# Need to create the search value as null for multiple search folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have multiple folders with corresponding items, in that having search option. If I clicked the checkbox on folder A in the search option, it will show their items (eg. consider it having 4 items) and If I click the another checkbox of folder B (eg. consider it having 4 items) along with the folder A, it will show totally 8 items of folder A and folder B. Now When I remove the folder A or folder B from the checkbox, it still showing the 8 items. But I need only the corresponding folder items selected.

Here are my code:

```
Checkbox: Core.component.Checkbox.extend({
    click: function () {
        console.log(this);
        var nav = this.get("controller").get('selectedNavigator');
        var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        Ember.run.schedule('sync', this, function () {
            Ember.run.schedule('render', this, function () {
                var states = this.get('parentView.itemStates');
                var values =  Object.keys(states).filter(function (key) {
                    return states[key];
                });

                if (values.length === 0) {
                    Core.Action('core:contentHome', {});
                } else {
                    this.set('parentView.model.values',values);
                    nav.publish();
                }

            });
        });
        return ret;
    }
})
```

I'm using Ember 1.4.0. I'm new to the ember.

Comment: Share your implementation in a Ember twiddle to debug.